# How to specify random coefficients priors in rstanarm?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, rstanarm

Suppose I have a following formula for a mixed effects model:

```
Performance ~ 1 + WorkingHours + Tenure + (1 + WorkingHours + Tenure || JobClass)
```

then I can specify priors for fixed slopes and fixed intercept as:

```
prior = normal(c(mu1,mu2), c(sd1,sd2), autoscale = FALSE)
prior_intercept = normal(mean, scale, autoscale = FALSE)
```

But how do I specify the priors for random slopes and intercept using

```
prior_covariance = decov(regularization, concentration, shape, scale)
```

(or)

```
lkj(regularization, scale, df)
```

if I know the variance between the slopes and intercepts and the correlation between them.
I am unable to understand how to specify the parameters for the above mixed effects formula.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're working in a Bayesian model, you aren't going to specify the correlations or variances. You're going to specify a likelihood distribution of covariance matrices (by way of the correlation matrix and vector of variances) by giving the values for a few parameters.

The `regularization` parameter is a positive real value that determines how likely things are to be correlated. A value of 1 is sort of the "anything's possible" option (this is the default). Values greater than 1 mean that you believe there are few, if any, correlations. Values less than 1 mean you believe there is a lot of correlation.

The `scale` parameter is related to the sum of the variances. In particular, the scale parameter is equal to the square root of the average variance.

The `concentration` parameter is used to control how the total variance is distributed among the different variables. A value of 1 is saying you don't have an expectation. Larger values say that you believe that the variables have similar proportions of the total variance. Values between 0 and 1 mean that you think there are dissimilar contributions.

The `shape` parameter is used for a Gamma distribution that acts as a prior on the `scale`.

Then, finally, `df` is your prior degrees of freedom.

So, `decov` and `lkj` are each giving you a different way to express your expectations about properties of the covariance matrix, but they won't let you specify which specific variables you believe to be correlated with which other specific variables. It should decide that as part of the model fitting process.

This is all from the [rstanarm documentation](http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/articles/glmer.html#priors-on-covariance-matrices)